# Regular Expression to find Q NOT followed by a U

Tags: python, regex

Here is my first question: I need to search a list of words and find any word that has a 'Q' or a 'q' NOT followed by a 'U' or a 'u'. An example will be Iraq, but not quality.

We just covered Regular Expressions in class and I am not sure if my Regular Expression will do the above.

I have the following Regular Expression

```
r"Qq[^Uu]"
```

but I am not sure if there is a better, more Pythonic, way to do the above.

Thanks for your mentoring in advance.

Waseem

Comment: Did you test it? Did it work?

Comment: @Waseem could you post an example along with expected output? What would be the output if the input is `Quran Iraq foo Iraq bar`

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the regex using `re.IGNORECASE` flag

```
>> pat=re.compile(r"q([^u]|$)",re.IGNORECASE )
>>> pat.search('Iraq')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7e7c9e0>
>>> pat.search('Quantum')
>>>
```

**NOTE**

`([^u]|$)` the alternation `$` ensures that the `q` is either followed by anything other than `u` or it can be a end of stirng `$`

**EDIT**

A negative look ahead can further reduce the regex as

```
>>> pat=re.compile(r"q(?!u)",re.IGNORECASE )
>>> pat.search('Iraq')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7f62de8>
>>> pat.search('Quantum')
>>>
```

Thanks to  nhahtdh for the suggestion

- `(?!u)`  Negative look ahead. Asserts that `q` is not followed by `u`

You can also add flag directly to the regex as

```
pat=re.compile(r"(?i)q(?!u)")
```

rather than providing flag to the `re.compile` method

Thanks to Avinash Raj for  the suggestion

Comment: It can be simplified with negative look-ahead.

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, negative look ahead would be better. will add to answer. Thank you

Comment: this `pat=re.compile(r"q(?!u)",re.IGNORECASE )` would be written as `pat=re.compile(r"(?i)q(?!u)")`

Comment: @AvinashRaj simpler. have added to the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
\b\w*q(?!u)\w*\b
```

or

```
(?=\b\w*q(?!u)\w*\b)\b\w+\b
```

Use this and apply `ignorecase` flag.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/17

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b\w*q(?!u)\w*\b', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"Iraq quality"
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: What's the need for adding `\w+?` before `q`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj there can be letter before `q`.OP wants to match a word

Answer (score 0):

another way is to match the bad words, match and capture the good words like so

```
\w*qu\w*|(\w*q\w*)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cU4uS8/2)

Comment: The effect is not correct in cases, let's say, `qu` and lone `q` both appear in the same word.

Comment: then it should not match and capture as the word has a `q` followed by `u`. Please show an example where it is not correct.

Comment: From my understanding, the OP wants to match a word where there is an instance of `q` not followed by `u`. With that interpretation, `quq` should be matched.

Comment: @nhahtdh I see your point now, I interpreted it as no `qu` in a word.